# Is it possible to draw using LIbreOffice Draw?

Tags: draw, libreoffice

I was looking for a program that would allow me to draw on Ubuntu Linux.

LibreOffice Draw is pre-installed so that looks like an option. To my surprise you cannot actually draw using LibreOffice draw. Or this feature is well hidden.

I am looking for a program that would allow me to draw lines and shapes similar to how we would do it in the real world. Not by manipulating objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you are looking for the Freeform Line (Curve) tool:

[image]

Otherwise, try software such as [GIMP](https://www.gimp.org/) that can edit bitmaps.

See also https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=11407.